# Recommended IDE for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a recommended IDE for developing Excel VBA macros that provides reasonable error reporting and code completion?

Currently, I'm using "Microsoft Visual Basic For Application" IDE which comes with Excel 2007, but so far, it is less than ideal.

Even a plug-in to Vim or Emacs will be great.

Comment: I found the VBA IDE quite up to the task most of the time. What are you missing?

Comment: @BenV That question is two years old now, and there was not a satisfactory answer (the accepted one suggests "use another language")

Comment: Given that VBA is a Microsoft language I'm unaware of anyone else developing an interpreter for, I'm afraid you are most likely stuck with MS's VBA IDE. I sympathize with your struggles, its limitations can be frustrating. But it could be much worse.

Comment: How about dumping VBA and going to VSTO? Then you can develop in Visual Studio. Woohoo! (Right?)

Answer (score 30):

I use and recommend [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/). Description from the website:

> Rubberduck is a very active open-source COM add-in project that integrates with the Visual Basic Editor to enable the features every programmer wants to have in their IDE. From unit testing to source control, from code inspections to refactorings, programming in VBA will never be the same.

Comment: wondering why this answer didn't get to the top.

Comment: @stucash because it's not a replacement/alternative IDE. It adds to VBE but doesn't really solve the fundamental problems with VBE

Comment: That said - even just getting the mouse wheel to actually do some scrolling is a massive bonus.

Answer (score 18):

You're pretty much stuck with MS's IDE, but there are some good add-ons available.  The two that I use constantly are:

- [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx)
- [Smart Indenter](http://oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this [SourceTools.xla](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/SourceTools.aspx). It is not a IDE, but an add-in for VBA that allows to save/read the all source files from your project into actual text files for use with source control. I have been using it for at least a year and I am very happy. It even allows direct use if CVS or SVN source control systems for commits/diff, but you don't have to do it from the IDE. And it is free and it comes with the source code unlocked if you want to tweak it.

Answer (score 3):

(I realize this question is 7 years old, but I had the same question so I'm just sharing a solution I went with.)

I've just recently started working with VBA with MS Excel and noticed it's really easy to lose all your code with the macros option if something crashed or was deleted.

Atom.io is a great IDE for any language to just easily type some code and save. I already use it for python and some easy scripting languages to check my syntax. I actually found a package for VBScript/VBA syntax highlighting: [here](https://atom.io/packages/language-vbscript)!

You can download it right in **Atom**:

- Click `File -> Settings -> Install`
- Search `language-vbscript`
- Click `Install`

And you're all set to open, edit, and save `.vba` files.

Comment: The question is about IDEs for VBA, I like Atom, and I love having github integration, but if I'm working on a multi module project, I'd need to reimport all times to test each change. I can't run the code directly from Atom, so Atom is not an IDE. (Integrated Development Environment).

Comment: Ah. That's very valid, I was super new to it so I had only done pretty basic multi-module projects @AndrewWynn